# Using .done and .fail for API POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using asp.net, c#, and jquery. I am using an API. When I get the response back, I want to do certain code when there is a success (.done) and when there is a failure (.fail).

**However, my code currently runs both .done and .fail code.** I do believe I need to reduce `$.ajax(settings)` from 2 times in my code to 1 time. I tried nesting .done and .fail in this, but I cannot figure out the correct syntax.

My issue is at  `$.ajax(settings).done(function (response)` and `$.ajax(settings).fail(function (xhr)` in my js file. My code currently seems to submit the POST to the API twice because I call the settings twice. Can anyone help solve my issue? I need to understand what my syntax should be for .done and .fail in my following code. I think I am just missing something small here.

Comment: You can also check out jQuery API Document about the jqXHR Object, which allow you to assign multiple callbacks on single request. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: if you handle done then done will be called irrespective of whether AJAX call succeeds or fails (you can think of it as finally of try-catch block in languages like c#).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. You shouldn't be running the same `ajax` call twice. Instead, you can chain your `done` and `fail` callbacks within the same `ajax` call.

Example:

```js
$(document).ready( () => {
  $.ajax('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .done( (data) => console.log(data) )
  .fail( (error) => console.error(error) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So your code should look like this instead:

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {

        'Get the response from Agile'

        'Payment Response'
        var responseType = response.response.response_type;
        var responseCode = response.response.response_code;
        var responseDesc = response.response.response_desc;

        'Indentification'
        var invoiceCode = "TEST";
        var invoiceInstance = "123";
        var nextNum = "1";
        var responseInvoiceNum = response.reference_id;
        var responseTransactionId = response.transaction_id;

        'Billing Information'
        var responseBillingFirstName = response.billing_address.first_name;
        var responseBillingLastName = response.billing_address.last_name;
        var responseBillingEmail = response.billing_address.email;
        var responseBillingPhone = response.billing_address.phone;
        var responseBillingStreet1 = response.billing_address.physical_address.street_line1;
        var responseBillingStreet2 = response.billing_address.physical_address.street_line2;
        var responseBillingCity = response.billing_address.physical_address.locality;
        var responseBillingState = response.billing_address.physical_address.region;
        var responseBillingZip = response.billing_address.physical_address.postal_code;
        var responseBillingCountry = response.billing_address.physical_address.country;

        'Payment Information'
        var cardType = response.card.card_type;
        var last4digits = response.card.last_4_account_number;
        var responseAmount = response.authorization_amount;


    })
    .fail(function (xhr) {

        var responseType = xhr.responseJSON.response.response_type;
        var responseCode = xhr.responseJSON.response.response_code;
        var responseDesc = xhr.responseJSON.response.response_desc;


    });
```